# How do I turn my sensor samples into a cleaner, more useful curve?

Tags: sensor, programming

This is for one of my fish tanks, which has dimmable LED lights. It's a bit of an experiment where I'd like to see what'll happen if the "sun" above the tank "rises" and "sets" in relation to the actual sun, as in, that glowing ball of fire in the sky. To that end I've hooked them up to a microcontroller reading a light sensor. What works really well is when there's a cloud moving in front of the sun, or the opposite. What's not working so well is to follow the course of day. I've logged the data for a few days. Here's two examples:

[image: Mostly overcast day]
*(mostly overcast day)*

[image: Some more sun]
*(this one had more sun in it, but also rain showers, and me working in that room during the late evening)*

While I'm very happy with the sensor data as such, my various attempts of cleaning it up (taking the average over 10 seconds, 60 seconds, and even up to 3600 seconds) are not really leading to a nice brightness progression of the fish tank LEDs' brightness setting¹. What I'm looking to get in the end is something more like this:

[image: Yearly average]
*(https://www.greenquarter.biz/green-engineering/daylight-harvesting/)*

Is there some mathematical way of working out the general trend of a curve which you know has the general property of first rising from 0 for a while and then falling back to 0 for a similar while, without having to be able to look into the future?²

### Update after comments from the community

It was suggested to (a) try a running average over one hour instead of one minute and (b) investigate a possible problem with how the data are being acquired and/or processed.

Averaging over one hour improved the curve considerably:

[image: avg. over 3600 seconds]

Also, it turned out that the sensor's gain setting was so low that it's effective resolution was limited to 4 or perhaps 5 bits. Increasing the gain from 4 to 64 improved that to 8-9 bits, which is much more useful. Here is a plot of one day, just the raw ADC output, not converted into lux and not averaged:

[image: raw ADC output]

My plan is now to rewrite the code to not calculate the lux at all anymore, but to average the integer numbers from the sensor's ADC over one hour and then map that to a number between 0.0 and 10.0 (or so) and use that as a factor for modifying the brightness setting.

---

¹No, it has nothing to do with [the human eye's lightness constancy](http://idol.union.edu/malekis/CVision2003/MainPage/Course%20Content/Perception%20of%20Brightness/PercepofBrightness.htm), I'm already compensating for that.

²If it matters, the microcontroller I'm using is an Atmel SAMD21, and while it doesn't have an FPU, it's sufficiently fast that I don't mind working with floating-point numbers.

Comment: Can you post the plots of the averages? I think averaging over 30-60 minutes should work.

Comment: That had only been an idea that I ditched before starting to log anything. Put it back in (also to see if averaging 3600 numbers once per second will end up having any side effects; quite a bit more than just 60) and will post another plot on Sunday. Thank you for the comment, @MBaz!

Comment: It looks like the sensor is heavily quantized, or there's a bug in your logging software, or both.  I'm seeing lots of level lines, and in the top plot it's bimodal between two points that definitely aren't just quantization.

Comment: @TimWescott it's possible that I'm at the resolution limit of the sensor. It goes from 0 to "a lot" but because of the enclosure it's in (with only a rather small piece of 92% transmission plexiglas for a window) it's not receiving a lot of light. At least that's my explanation for why it only goes up to 6-ish lux in the plots. I wasn't too worried about that so far as it still seems to be good enough for what I want to do. I'll leave it running for now (already went to bed) but maybe change to logging the raw ADC output on Sunday instead of the calculated lux number.

Comment: Are you using the output in realtime for some regulation purpose, or will it only be used later? Perhaps you can do a least squares fit of a mid-day-centered Gaussian, or whatever shape the nice looking example curves have.

Comment: It's for realtime regulation. A fit, as I understand it, would not be such a good tool - because what if there's a thunderstorm in the afternoon and the light _does_ get more bright again in the evening, before fading out the usual way...

Comment: Just plotted the running 60-minute average for Saturday and added it above. Also looked at the sensor datasheet and the sources of various libraries. It seems that it has different gain settings (up to a gain of 64 it seems) for precisely the reason that people might put it into a little box with a small window and I've been running it at gain 1. Even as it is, though, the data looks much more usable already!

Comment: Next update: after having watched the log output print the raw ADC values from the sensor (as opposed to the luxes), I have to concede that I was effectively running at a resolution of 4, perhaps 5 bits. Ouch. It seems upping the gain to 16 and taking the running average over 3600 seconds, that might already be the solution. Which makes me wonder how to proceed with this question? Do I leave the question as it is, fully implement the changes, and if it indeed works, write my own answer? Or do I rework the question and leave it unanswered?